# How to create hidden text field based on 'Yes' or 'No' response

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Report which includes a select list of 'yes' and 'no' for a box labelled 'DAS submitted'. Is it possible to use the dynamic action for select list that when the user selects 'yes', another text field appears which allows the user to input the 'DAS ID', but stays hidden if user selects 'no'?

I have tried playing around with the action buttons but can't seem to link it properly. As well as trying to follow these instructions (https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3703262/how-to-hide-text-field-item-based-on-true-or-false-cases-in-oracle-apex) but cannot find them clear enough from step 2. I am using Oracle Apex 22.2

Comment: Have you looked at using an interactive grid instead of an interactive report ? On interactive grid you can create dynamic actions at row level. That'd be way easier than trying to mimic that functionality in an interactive report

Comment: @KoenLostrie For the way the data needs to be portrayed, an interactive report is better for this. Would it still be possible?

Comment: An interactive report does not have this functionality. It could be possible but it is going to require a lot of custom coding. You'll have to use APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST to render the select lists and the text field and then write javascript to listen for the change on a particular row and show/hide the other APEX_ITEM.TEXT cell in that same row. If you want to spend the time figuring that out, go ahead. It's your project and your time.

Comment: Almost everything is possible in APEX, but as a developer it is strongly advised to go for a solution that is solid,upgrade proof and maintainable. This solution most probably will be none of those. So in my opinion, an interactive report doesn't make sense since that functionality can be achieved declaratively with an IG.

Comment: @KoenLostrie okay, i'll put it as an interactive grid. How would I go about adding the dynamic action button? Also, the report allowed for new data/rows to be created and edited, but now it is changed to a grid, these options seemed to have disappeared. Would it still be possible to edit/add new rows of data?

Comment: Hiding/showing won't be possible. How would that work in terms of layout ? You could enable/disable a field with a dyn action. 
I can put together an example but not right now. Google "IG Cookbook Update for 19.2" and install the cookbook app. It has many advanced examples, maybe what you want already exists in there